# How i solve the error in fragment with android nav component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bottomnav

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.farmbuy/com.farmbuy.farmer.FarmersActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no start destination defined via app:startDestination for com.farmbuy:id/farmer_nav_graph
at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:61)
at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1049)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:633)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:586)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:551)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:533)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:238)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:109)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:784)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
at com.farmbuy.farmer.FarmersActivity.onCreate(FarmersActivity.kt:13)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have not spcified a start destination in your nav graph. There must be one start destination which is the fragment that you want to show to the user when user launches the app.

Add this in your navigation graph `app:startDestination="@id/fragmentId`. Here fragmentId is the id of the fragment which should show when app is first launched

Answer (score 0):

```
I solved this by adding the start destination in the nav_graph

<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/farmer_nav_graph"
```

*app:startDestination="@id/farmersProductsFragment*
>